# Avoiding rerender using callback in child component whenever state in parent changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having some issues with components being rerendered to often whenever the parent component has updated its state.

I have a simple `User`component which displays a name. The `App` component uses `useState` to store multiple users. Whenever the provided callback `onClick` is being run all components are rerendered, this decreases performance. I have tried using `useCallback` in order to prevent this from happening. The code can be run [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/no-arrow-func-render-62ffq). How can I prevent the other components being rerendered whenever the parent updates the users state?

```js
const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "Cory" },
    { id: 2, name: "Meg" },
    { id: 3, name: "Bob" }
  ]);

  const deleteUser = useCallback(id => {
    setUsers(users => users.filter(user => user.id !== id));
  }, []);

  const renderUser = user => {
    return <User key={user.id} user={user} onClick={deleteUser} />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <ul>{users.map(renderUser)}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

User

```js
const User = props => {
  const onDeleteClick = () => {
    props.onClick(props.user.id);
  };

  console.log(`${props.user.name} just rendered`);
  return (
    <li>
      <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick={onDeleteClick} />
      {props.user.name}
    </li>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

use `React.memo` in your children component

```
export default React.memo(User);
```

Comment: Thanks iamhuynq!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `React.memo` in `User` Component to stop re-rendering of the Component.

Working Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/no-arrow-func-render-eziql

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Yash Joshi!